# Linkage order under g++ compiler on the command line

Tags: c++, g++, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2

I'm having a slight problem with getting the g++ line correct for the appropriate compiling of my files.
I've created my own library that has a dependancy on bcm2835.h and then a main problem that calls this library. Files I have are :
5383comm.cpp and 5383comm.h <- My own library file and header that calls bcm2835.h.
dbcomm.cpp <- includes ncurses.h and 5383comm.h

ncurses and bcm2835 are in standard system folders (ie they're included by  while 5383comm.h/cpp are  in the same directory as the main file (included by "filename.h".

Working ona  Raspberry Pi 2
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: What is the error you are getting?  What is your current command-line you are using?

Comment: Hi,first you don't have dependencies on .h files but on libraries. If I understood correctly you want to compile dbcomm.cpp using 5383comm.cpp as library. 5383comm.cpp uses bcm2835 as library with ncurses. right?